# Spring Boot - start ActiveMQ Web Console on startup

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have a Spring Boot app that automatically starts up an ActiveMQ broker (vm://localhost): it works, I can successfully send and receive messages.

I would like Spring Boot to also start the *ActiveMQ Web Console* e.g. http://localhost:8161/admin (much like it can with the H2 Database console).

**Question**: how do I make a Spring Boot app start the ActiveMQ Web Console?

**Bonus Points**: for a specific Spring @profile only?

thanks in advance

**Note**: I have already reviewed [How to enable web console on ActiveMq embedded broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211770/how-to-enable-web-console-on-activemq-embedded-broker) but this requires the use the hawtio which I do not want to/cannot use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable web console on ActiveMq embedded broker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211770/how-to-enable-web-console-on-activemq-embedded-broker)

Comment: r.e. the possible duplicate: the accepted answer is to use hawt.io - I do not want to use this.

Comment: if you cannot use hawtio you have to build and embedd this artifact https://github.com/apache/activemq/tree/master/activemq-web-console as a jar and start a server as done here https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-web-console/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/web/tool/Main.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Web Console is a web app that can be downloaded and started in any servlet container such as Tomcat.

Here are some steps.

Enable ActiveMQ for JMX use in activemq.xml. That is - enable it in the broker tag: `<broker useJmx="true"` .. and

And make sure `createConnector` is `true`.

```
<managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="true"/>
</managementContext>
```

Download the .war from Maven. Better use the same version as the broker.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/activemq-web-console/5.14.5/

Then setup the following JVM properties (JAVA_OPTS). Note that URL and ports may differ if you have changed them.

```
-Dwebconsole.type=properties 
-Dwebconsole.jms.url=tcp://localhost:61616 
-Dwebconsole.jmx.url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

If you have no Tomcat (or servlet container) and prefer to run your Spring boot apps with "java -jar .. " - you can do the same with the Web console.

Example below using this app: https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner

Had to add jstl jar as it wasn't bundled with webapp-runner.

```
java -Dwebconsole.type=properties -Dwebconsole.jms.url=tcp://localhost:61616 -Dwebconsole.jmx.url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi -cp jstl-1.2.jar:webapp-runner.jar webapp.runner.launch --port 8085 activemq-web-console-5.14.5.war
```

The admin console will be hosted on localhost at port 8085. This is just a starter. You may want to add fail-over, security etc etc. YMMV

Comment: Do we need to add <import resource="${activemq.base}/conf/jetty.xml" /> into activemq.xml? If yes, How we can add it. If we are using war

Comment: for me this solution is not working:
the web console logs say `No broker is found at any of the 1 configured urls`
in the artemis server I have activated jmx with `configuration.setJMXManagementEnabled(true);`
but this configuration object does not provide any way to set this `<managementContext createConnector="true"/>`
how can i do this without using an xml file ?

Comment: This answer is for ActiveMQ Classic not Artemis