# ActiveMQ Embedded web console and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

According to [this documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management-console.html) I must be able to access ActiveMQ console by the following url: http://localhost:8161/console

I use ActiveMQ in embedded mode via my Spring Boot application. ActiveMQ is working fine but I unable to reach http://localhost:8161/console

How to configure Spring Boot and ActiveMQ embedded in order to be able to access web console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot - start ActiveMQ Web Console on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108318/spring-boot-start-activemq-web-console-on-startup)

Comment: It May help you https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jms-activemq-example

Comment: I know how to use hawtio mentioned on  the following page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211770/how-to-enable-web-console-on-activemq-embedded-broker but I don't know how to start native ActiveMQ web console with Spring Boot and ActiveMQ Embedded

Comment: FWIW, the documentation you cited regarding the management console is for ActiveMQ Artemis, but it appears you're actually using ActiveMQ 5.x. To be clear, both brokers have management consoles running on `8161`.

Comment: Even embedded one?

Comment: No one from the provided links doesn't answer this question. Please carefully read the question.

Comment: the provided links don't work. Have you figured out @alexanoid ?